# send passkey to site from vb.net application

Tags: php, vb.net, security, key

i have the following situation:

i have an application that loads up an URL.
i have to verify that the URL has been loaded by the application and not a browser... and it has to be MY application, not just any application.. (so browsercheck in the php page is not an option)
to do so i was thinking of something like this: app loads a url, recives a key, processes that key and sends it back processed. the php page checks if it has been processed correctly and if it has then it is ok.

problem is: my vb.net application can be decompiled and within minutes you know how to validate the key. i need something that is secure. any tipps on how to do this? 
thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also do this over the SSL/TLS, since traffic can be intercepted.
And, there is no any 100% solution on this scenario. You can obfuscate code, do not use key directly but build it from parts, masking it, whatever else. But this will just take some more time to decompile.

Comment: already tried to obfuscate but without any success.. its still way to easy to understand.. any additional tipp?

Comment: thanks! a the end i decided to add another 20 functions (unused) with different codes each, and the Whole project has been obfuscated, and the codes have been obfuscated too by using ascii  on some letters, and i made the server side stronger with ip checking and each ip can not contact the page more then once every 30 seconds. this should do it.. :) thanks for your help and suggestions!